# AWS with nodejs failed, error of BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use this npm https://github.com/RiptideElements/s3fs and got this error of

```
Unhandled rejection BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou: Your previous request to create the
 named bucket succeeded and you already own it.
```

In my app.js I do

```
var s3 = require('./config/db.js');
var fs = require('fs');
var S3FS = require('s3fs');

var s3_config = require('./config/s3_config');
var s3fsImpl = new S3FS(s3_config.bucket,{
  accessKeyId : s3_config.key,
  secretAccessKey : s3_config.secret
});
s3fsImpl.create();
```

Any thought or hint why I'm getting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3fs):

> `s3fs.create(options[, callback])`
>
> Creates a new bucket on S3.

You appear to be calling the method to create a new S3 bucket. Does the bucket already exist?

Comment: yeah should do this when I have existing bucket with the same name, solved thanks!